# UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter with degree lines

Tags: ios, uibezierpath

i am creating a circle with

```
+(UIBezierPath *)circleShape:(CGRect)originalFrame{
    CGRect frame = [self maximumSquareFrameThatFits:originalFrame];
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(160, 150)
                          radius:100
                          startAngle:0
                          endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360)
                          clockwise:YES];   
    return aPath;
}
```

I want to add 2 lines vertical and horizontal through the center and extend past the bounds of the clircle
I have tried addLineToPoint but i get nothing in the circle

TIA

Thanks, im adding lines like so and apart from playing with positioning the line extending past the bounds of the circle are displaying but im guessing the lines in the circle are the same color as the circle, so not visible. Do i need to create the lines in another method then use appendPath? so i can assign a different color.

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(160, 150)
radius:100
startAngle:0
endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360)
clockwise:YES];
[aPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame)
+ 0.30000 *  CGRectGetWidth(frame),CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.15000
* CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
[aPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.27634
* CGRectGetWidth(frame),  CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.10729 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
[aPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.97553 *
CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.39549 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];

[aPath closePath];
return aPath;
```

Comment: You should show the code you tried to add the lines, and explain exactly what result it gave you.

Comment: Note: when posting code, you have to indent every line with four spaces. Or select all of the code, and click on the code button `{ }`

Answer (score 0):

After you draw the circle, the current graphics location is the last point on the circle.  If you call `addLineToPoint`, the line is drawn from the last point on the circle to the end point that you pass to `addLineToPoint`.

To start a line that's not attached to the endpoint of the circle, use `moveToPoint` to change the current graphics location.

Note that if you `stroke` the path and then `fill` it, then the lines inside the circle will not be shown.  That's because the fill operation will overwrite any pixels that were drawn inside the circle.  If you `fill` the path first, and then `stroke` it, then the lines will be drawn on top of the circle (provided that the stroke and fill colors are different).